# Can I use regex expression in c# with switch case?

Tags: c#, regex

Can I write switch case in c# like this?

```
switch (string)

case [a..z]+

//   do something

case [A..Z]+

//   do something

....
```

Comment: each `case` statement must be a constant value and not computed.

Comment: Are you using c# 7? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pattern-matching-in-c-sharp-7-0/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes you can in C# 7 (and nobody noticed I had used the incorrect range character in the character class `..` instead of `-`). Updated now with a slightly more useful example that actually works:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string[] strings = {"ABCDEFGabcdefg", "abcdefg", "ABCDEFG"};
Array.ForEach(strings, s => {
    switch (s)
    {
        case var someVal when new Regex(@"^[a-z]+$").IsMatch(someVal):
            Console.WriteLine($"{someVal}: all lower");
            break;
        case var someVal when new Regex(@"^[A-Z]+$").IsMatch(someVal):
            Console.WriteLine($"{someVal}: all upper");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine($"{s}: not all upper or lower");
            break;
    }
});
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGabcdefg: not all upper or lower
abcdefg: all lower
ABCDEFG: all upper
```

Comment: how "someString" is taking part of this nice expressions?

Comment: The string `s` is assigned to `var someVal` and used in the evaluation of the condition, and is subsequently available in the statements following the matching condition.

Answer (score 12):

A minor refinement on David's excellent answer using _ as a discard.
Just a very simple string value as an example.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string userName = "Fred";
        int something = 0;

        switch (true)
        {                
            case bool _ when Regex.IsMatch(userName, @"Joe"):
                something = 1;
                break;

            case bool _ when Regex.IsMatch(userName, @"Fred"):
                something = 2;
                break;

            default:            
                break;
        }    
        Console.WriteLine(something.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better. But some people might say `switch(true){}` is bad practice.

Comment: Like any compromise it works best when you understand the trade-off. You get much cleaner syntax than If... Else, but need to be wary of adding duplicate conditions.

Answer (score 10):

Starting with C# 8.0, the answer is now YES!... sort of.

With 8.0, the [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) was introduced. You can use that to match many different styles of patterns as show below.

```
string myValueBeingTested = "asdf";
        
string theResultValue = myValueBeingTested switch
{
    var x when 
        Regex.IsMatch(x, "[a..z]+") => "everything is lowercase",
    var y when
        Regex.IsMatch(y, "[A..Z]+") => "EVERYTHING IS UPPERCASE",
    "Something Specific"            => "The Specific One",
    _                               => "The default, no match scenario"
};
```

How it works: The *switch expression* needs a variable that it can feed the results into. The above sample uses `theResultValue` variable for that. Next you pass into the *switch* what is referred to as the *range expression* represented by `myValueBeingTested` above. The familiar *case* construct is replaced with a *pattern expression* followed by the `=>` token and together referred to as an *expressionn arm*. Anything on the right side of the *arm token* will end up in the result variable.

Normally the *switch expression* requires that patterns be a compile-time constant, and you cannot execute arbitrary code inside a *switch expression*. However we can use a *case gaurd* pattern by using the `when` clause to make use of *Regex* as shown above. Each case needs to be wired up in a distinct *arm* with distinct throw-away variables, (`x` and `y` above).

The 3rd *arm* shown above is a compile-time constant string to match some specific text if desired. The 4th *arm* shown above uses the `_` pattern, which is a sort of wildcard similar to the old `default:` keyword. You can also use `null` instead of, or in addition to `_` to handle null cases separately from anything else.

Try it out in my [.NET Fiddle sample here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aLfXos).

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private void fauxSwitch(string caseSwitch)
{
    if(Regex.Match(caseSwitch, @"[a..z]+").Success)
    {
        //do something
        return;
    }

    if(Regex.Match(caseSwitch, @"[A..Z]+").Success)
    {
        //do something
        return;
    }

    /*default*/
    //do something
}
```

Although, Pattern matching in C#7 is probably the better option.

Answer (score 2):

No. In C# (prior to 7) the switch statement only accepts constant values.

Using more complex expressions as you've suggested is a feature known as 'pattern matching' in the functional programming world.

Pattern matching is included in C#7