# How can I use named group in C# regex switch/case?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a code that checks if it matches to a regular expression then prints matched string.

I found other question [Can I use regex expression in c# with switch case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707983), but `IsMatch` method only returns boolean so I couldn't retrieve named group string.

```
var filepath = @"path/to/file.txt";
foreach (string line File.ReadLines(filepath))
{
    switch (line)
    {
        case var s when new Regex(@"^(?<UserName>\w+) moved to (?<Position>\w+)$").IsMatch(s):
            // I have to know <UserName> and <Position> here.
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'd suggest moving the regex construction itself outside the switch block - both for readability and to allow it to be reused.

Then, instead of using `IsMatch`, use the `Match` to return a `Match`, which you'd then check for success (potentially using a C# pattern match). For example:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        RunTest("Jon moved to XYZ");
        RunTest("Not a match");
    }

    private static readonly Regex UserMovementRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<UserName>\w+) moved to (?<Position>\w+)$");
    private static void RunTest(string line)
    {
        switch (line)
        {
            case string _ when UserMovementRegex.Match(line) is { Success: true } match:
                Console.WriteLine($"UserName: {match.Groups["UserName"]}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Position: {match.Groups["Position"]}");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("No match");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `{ Success: true } match` part has two purposes:

- It checks that the match is successful
- It captures the result in a new `match` variable that you can use in the body of the `case` label

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values with Groups:

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<UserName>\w+) moved to (?<Position>\w+)$");
var match = regex.Match(blobContent);
if (match.Success)
{
   string userName= m.Groups["UserName"].Value;
   string position= m.Groups["Position"].Value;
}
```

Comment: I believe the main aim of the question is asking how to do this easily within a switch statement, with the matching being part of the "test" for the case, and then using the groups within the body of the case.